# Улучшить описание метки [математика]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки

Мне кажется, стоит улучшить текущее описание метки [математика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0). Как минимум, добавить объяснение, когда её стоит использовать.

[Этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1156835/398802) и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1156754/398802) вопросы, например, используют её для нахождения минимума/максимума и суммы элементов массива. Формально, это математика тоже, но думаю, стоит использовать эту метку для более математических вопросов или вовсе для вопросов чисто по математике, без необходимости писать программы.